# enable RLANG on SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: r, sas, rlang

I want to use R on my SAS EG 7.1
When I ran the following code to check if R is enabled I figured out that it is not

```
proc options option=RLANG;
run;
```

Log :

> SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M3
>
> NORLANG Disables SAS from executing R language statements.

I would like to know how to enable RLANG on my SAS so that I can use **PROC IML** etc.

Comment: From the SAS docs on the message you received: "If the SAS log contains this statement, you do not have permission to call R from the SAS system."  Do you have admin access for your SAS installation?

Comment: Yes I can get admin access-or at-least I can give directions to administrator to enable it. But I want to know how.

Comment: You or your SAS admin, need to add `RLANG` to the workspace server configuration (.cfg) file.  You cannot do it inside of Enterprise Guide.

Comment: You're using EG with a server?  Or local SAS?

Comment: I am using EG with a server.

Answer (score 2):

Add `RLANG` to the workspace server configuration file.  This has to be done at startup of the server, and cannot be done inside of Enterprise Guide.